# json parsing ,Button on click action in android

Tags: android

first sorry for my bad English ,I am parsing my JSON data successfully ,its working fine but ,in JSON data i am parsing URL, I don't how to place URL dynamically on click action

```
    {
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "wbsite":"htt://www.facebook.com"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",
                "wbsite": "https://www.google.co.in",

                }
        },     
  ]
}
```

when I am click button it will goes to app to website dynamically any one help me how to do that

```
    @Override public void onClick(View v) { 
Log.d("MR.bool", "Button1 was clicked "); 
}
```

Comment: Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://" + websiteUrl));
                this.startActivity(browserIntent);

Comment: Your English is real bad, please explain in correct manner what you really want, or write in Hindi.

Comment: JSON does nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this must be listview and you were able to parse the JSON to obtain a string variable containing the website. If so like @sumit said

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://" +    websiteUrl)); 
this.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

For more information a try android [document](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/components/intents-common.html#Browser). I hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**On click event of button, just add the following code**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Dynamically change the url:**

```
String strImagePath = results.getString("imageupload");
imgProfile.setTag("" + strImagePath);       
Picasso.with(context).load(strImagePath).into(imgProfile);
```

In the above code, **imageupload** is my json param name, kindly change it as per your requirement and **imgProfile** is my imageview.

Comment: it working fine when i am using single url ,but my requirement is i want to do this dynamically ,in my json obeject have multi urls @parth Bhayani

Comment: If this is helpful to you, you can upvote my answer.

Comment: Hey, I have updated the above answer, please look into it.